# Using lists in a pandas query

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am performing a query on a DataFrame:

```
Index Category
1     Foo
2     Bar
3     Cho
4     Foo
```

I would like to return the rows where the category is "Foo" or "Bar".
When I use the code:

```
df.query("Catergory==['Foo','Bar']")
```

This works fine and returns:

```
Index Category
1     Foo
2     Bar
4     Foo
```

However in future I will want the filter to be changed dynamically so I wrote:

```
filter_list=['Foo','Bar']
df.query("Catergory==filter_list")
```

Which threw out the error:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'filter_list' is not defined
```

Other variations I tried with no success were:

```
df.query("Catergory"==filter_list)
df.query("Catergory=="filter_list)
```

Respectively producing:

```
ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `@` to reference variables in `query`:

```
filter_list=['Foo','Bar']

df.query("Category == @filter_list")
```

Output:

```
   Index Category
0      1      Foo
1      2      Bar
3      4      Foo
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `isin` method.

```
df.query('Category.isin(@filter_list)')
```

Comment: I find this syntax much more clear than the accepted answer (for which I would expect exact list equality). Works for me in Pandas version 1.2.4.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[1,2,3,4],'Category':['Foo','Bar','Cho','Foo']})
filter_list = ['Foo','Bar']

df.query(f'Category=={filter_list}')
```

Comment: You can also write ```df.query(f'Category in {filter_list}')```, which may be more readable

Comment: `df.query("Category in @filter_list")` works as well